# ¿Por qué no puedo acceder como usuario 'bookorama' a mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Intento ingresar a la base de datos como usuario 'bookorama' pero no puedo acceder ,  ingreso la contraseña correctamente , pero me dice acceso denegado

Abajo se muestra la tabla 'user' de la base de datos *mysql* [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a restablecer la contraseña de la siguiente forma:

```
// iniciamos sesión con root
$prompt> mysql -u root -p
// seleccionamos mysql como bd
mysql> use mysql;
// actualizamos la contraseña
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("nuevaclave") where User='bookorama';
// refrescamos los cambios para que surtan efecto
mysql> flush privileges;
// salimos
mysql> quit
```

Después intenta acceder con la contraseña nueva.

Importante que utilices el comando `flush privileges;` para que tengan efecto los cambios.